# How to initialize a read-only, global, associative array in Bash?

Tags: bash, array

I execute the following code in Bash version "GNU bash, Version 4.2.39(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)":

```
function foobar {
  declare -rgA FOOBAR=([foo]=bar)
}
foobar
declare -p FOOBAR
# Output: declare -Ar FOOBAR='()'
```

Why doesn't Bash initialize `FOOBAR` with `([foo]=bar)` according to `declare -p`? The same declaration works outside of a function, e.g.

```
declare -rgA FOOBAR=([foo]=bar)
declare -p FOOBAR
# Output: declare -Ar FOOBAR='([foo]="bar" )'
```

Similarly the following code but without `FOOBAR` being read-only works:

```
function foobar {
  declare -gA FOOBAR
  FOOBAR=([foo]=bar)
}
foobar
declare -p FOOBAR
# Output: declare -A FOOBAR='([foo]="bar" )'
```

Is this a bug or feature?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I would use bashbug to send it off the mailing list. `-g` for declare is new in 4.2, so I wouldn't be surprised if this case was missed in testing.

Comment: I have reported this potential bug to bug-bash@gnu.org.

Answer (score 4):

```
function foobar {
  declare -rgA 'FOOBAR=([foo]=bar)'
}
foobar
declare -p FOOBAR
```

(note the extra quotes) works for me.

You'll even find that in:

```
function foobar {
  var="something tricker"
  declare -rgA 'FOOBAR=([foo]=$var)'
}
foobar
declare -p FOOBAR
```

$var is expanded even if it's quoted.